# What does partial mean in owl

Tags: semantic-web, owl

I have been reading [this](http://owl.man.ac.uk/2003/why/latest/) document and i encountered the following:

```
Class(a:adult partial 
  annotation(rdfs:comment "Things that are adult.")
```

I understand annotation but what is partial/complete  and is it used these days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`partial` here means the class `adult` is a specialization of the annotation, like in `Class(a:Cat partial a:Animal))`.

The `complete` specifier means an equivalence, like in the example given in your link:

```
Class(a:animal_lover complete
    intersectionOf(restriction(a:has_pet minCardinality(3)) a:person))
```

which states that an `animal_lover` **is** a `person` who has at least 3 pets.

Comment: I'm guessing when there is no class specified, like in the example in the question, the class is meant to be owl:Thing

Comment: kindly check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31103720/should-rif-rules-be-inside-the-ontology